# Hibernate - Raw Query execution_KEY Words Issue in query?

Tags: sql, hibernate, keyword

The setup consists of Hibernate 3.   Am trying to execute the raw query as it is. The setup works fine for other simple queries , db inserts & updates.

The query in issue is :

```
   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 29 [
          SELECT keyMain, value FROM (select distinct K.[key] as keyMain,
            ( SELECT value FROM com.trans.dto.Resources as L WHERE L.[key] = K.[key] 
              and L.lang_code = 'A11' ) as value from com.trans.dto.Resources as  K ) 
              as test order by keyMain ]
```

Resources is the table & has mapping setup in hibernate.cfg.xml

1. I was under a thought "KEY" is name of one of the column which can not be changed. How do i escape key words ?
2. If not 1, then is the multi selects in sub query.

Please advise. Any suggestion is of great help.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-quotedidentifiers):

```
You can force Hibernate to quote an identifier in the generated SQL
by enclosing the table or column name in backticks in the mapping document. 
Hibernate will use the correct quotation style for the SQL Dialect. 
This is usually double quotes, but the SQL Server uses brackets and MySQL uses backticks.
```

So, try to escape your field with double quotes or with square parenthesis('[key]').

Comment: Thank you Alex. But I tried following options [Key] , `[Key]` , "[key]", "key" nothing worked.  It appears crazy but tried all of these.  Unable to change the column name due to ripple effect of code changes in other applications.